# Error message: Protocol wrong type for socket with py2neo

Tags: python, sockets, neo4j, py2neo

I am using py2neo to query a set of data from a neo4j graph database and to create relationships between nodes once appropriate information has been achieved within a python script.

Here is a basic structure of the script.

```
import py2neo

### get a set of data from a graph database  
graph = Graph()
query =  graph.cypher.execute("MATCH (p:LABEL1))-[:relationship]->(c:Label2 {Name:'property'} \
 RETURN p.Id, p.value1, c.value2 LIMIT 100")

### do a data analysis within a python script here
~ ~ ~ 

### update newly found information through the analysis to the graph database

tx = graph.cypher.begin()
qs1 = "UNWIND range(0,{size}-1) AS r \ 
       MATCH (p1:Label1 {Id:{xxxx}[r]}),(p2:Label2 {Id:{yyyy}[r]}) \
       MERGE (p1)-[:relationship {property:{value}[r]]->(p2)"
tx.append(qs1, parameters = {"size":size, \ 
                             "xxxx":xxxx, \
                             "yyyy":yyyy, \
                             "value":value})
tx.commit()
```

The script does perform as it is supposed to do when the query results are limited to 100, but when I increase 200 or above, the program crashes, leaving the following error message:

--> 263                 tx.commit()

SocketError: Protocol wrong type for socket

Unfortunately, besides the above statement, there is no other useful information that may hint what the problem might be. Did anyone have this sort of problem and could you suggest what the underlying issues may be?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked into this in much depth.
I ran into the same error when using:

```
tx = graph.cypher.begin()
tx.append("my cypher statement, i.e. MATCH STUFF")
tx.process()
....
tx.commit()
```

I was appending 1000 statements between each `process` call, and every 2000 statements I'd `commit`.
When I reduce the number of statements between process & commit to 250/500 it works fine (similar to you limiting to 100).

The actual error in the stack trace is from python's http/client:

```
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 888, in send
self.sock.sendall(data)
OSError: [Errno 41] Protocol wrong type for socket
```

Which is this an [EPROTOTYPE](https://docs.python.org/2/library/errno.html#errno.EPROTOTYPE) error, so it's happening on the client side and not in neo4j.

Are you on OS X? (I am.) This looks like it could be the issue:
[Chasing an EPROTOTYPE Through Rust, Sendto, and the OSX Kernel With C-Reduce](http://erickt.github.io/blog/2014/11/19/adventures-in-debugging-a-potential-osx-kernel-bug/). I don't know enough about underlying socket behaviour to tell you why reducing the amount we're sending over the connection removes the race condition.